# jQuery UI Autocomplete: minLength in a textarea, is there a way to begin counting from 0 in every new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

At the moment, I'm working on a `textarea` that allows the user to input predefined sentences. So, the user does not have to type in all those sentences.

The only thing I would like to change is, the `minlength` is set to 3, that works perfectly fine for the first line in the `textarea`. But of course in Line 2, it shows all entries without waiting for `minlength`, because `minlength=3` is true because of the text line before.

How could I reset or set back the min length in a new line of text?

**JS**

```
$("#AutoCompleteSentenceSuggestion")
      .autocomplete({
          minLength: 3,
          source: function (request, response) {
              $.getJSON("/AutoCompleteFeatures/AutoCompleteSentenceSuggestion", {
                  term: extractLast(request.term)
              }, response);
          },
          focus: function () {
              return false;
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
              var terms = split(this.value);
              terms.pop();
              terms.push("\u2022" + " " + ui.item.value);
              terms.push("");
              this.value = terms.join("\n");
              return false;
          }
      });
```

Update with HTML Markup:
**HTML**

```
<table class="table-textarea">
            <tr>
                <td class="style-class-2" rowspan="2">4</td>
                <td class="style-class-3">Additional Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.additionalInformation)
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like or do you have a fiddle example? Since you're adding a new line, you may need to treat this like a 'tag' style autocomplete. See: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. My HTML is pretty simple, I included it, as an update of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer this up, using the example I mentioned in my comment.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yfdjyq79/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  function split(val) {
    return val.split("\n");
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push("\u2022 " + ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("\r\n");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

You will want to move your `source` portions of course. I updated the `split()` and the `join()` within `select`. Using `\r\n` is not required, but I felt it was important to use for a cross platform solution. Not all browsers will use this as the end of line, so I only seek `\n` as the delimiter.

**UPDATE**

Here is an update that will prevent new entries from firing when the term is less then 3 characters.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yfdjyq79/5/

**JS Snippet**

```
  source: function(request, response) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    var resp;
    var lastTerm = extractLast(request.term);
    if (lastTerm.length >= 3) {
      response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, lastTerm));
    }
  },
```

You can store the value up front but you cannot call `$(selector).autocomplete("option", "minLength")` since you're initializing it. That would have been convenient. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yfdjyq79/7/

Comment: Hi @Twisty, first of all thank you for your effort and time to answer. But the problem that I described above still exists in your fiddle. When I type in "Act" in the first line, autocomplete suggests ActionScript. Totally fine. But when I enter the second line and only type in A, all suggestions with including A appear, minlength is ignored in this case, and thats what I want to fix. So in the second line when I write A, nothing should happen, only with the minlength of 3, just like in the first line.

Comment: @RawMVC I see what you're describing, so I will see what I can do about that. I suspect just it just has to be a condition before the filter.

Comment: @RawMVC check out the update and the final example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yfdjyq79/7/

Comment: Aside, I see this as a bad way to collect a list of data. Personally, I would use a `<ul><li><input type='text'></li></ul>` style list. This way you can add more as needed, combine them later, and make a delete button. More overall control.